# When a fibration over a projective manifold is projective?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex manifold, $B$ be a complex projective manifold, consider a smooth fibration $\pi:X\rightarrow B$ such that all the fibers of $\pi$ are simply-connected projective manifolds, then is $X$ a projective manifold?
As we know, if we remove the simply-connected restriction, we will get a counter-example: Hopf surface, which is an elliptic fibration over $\mathbb CP^1$.
In 1954, Kodaira prove as a corollary of his famous Embedding theorem that if all the fibers are complex projective spaces, then the total space $X$ is a projective manifold. So naturally, we will ask that can we generalize the complex projective space to a broader range? For example, simply-connected projective manifold?

In a paper of Cao Junyan[《On the approximation of Kähler manifolds by algebraic varieties》](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00208-014-1097-4)p405, he seemed have proved that if all the fiber $Y$ of $\pi$ satisfying $H^i(Y,\mathcal O)=0$ for $i>0$, then the total space $X$ is a projective manifold. By Leray's spectral sequence, $H^i(X,\mathcal O)=H^i(B,\mathcal O)$ can be deduced from $H^i(Y,\mathcal O)=0$, I am not sure it is indeed the case since he never claimed the conclusion can be deduced in this way in his paper, what's more there are also some extra conditions(maybe unnecessary) added on the total space.

So my question is what's the necessary and sufficient conditon on the fiber to make the total space a projective manifold? simply-connected? or some higher cohomology groups vanishing? or some other conditions?
Any comment is welcome! Thanks in advance.

**Added later**: as commented by Michael Albanese and Jason starr, the simply-connected case is already proved not suffice. And as commented blow, we now assume that the total space $X$ is a Kähler manifold.

Comment: Although you have slightly modified the question, I think you should still link to your MSE question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3840348/39599

Comment: That is not true.  Let $Y$ be a complex projective simply connected manifold that admit a holomorphic automorphism $f$ fixing no ample divisor class.  Let $\widetilde{X}$ be the product of $Y$ and $\mathbb{C}^\times$.  Let $X$ be the quotient by the cyclic group acting via $f$ and scaling by a complex unit with nonunit modulus.  The projection onto the second factor is a smooth, proper holomorphic map to an elliptic curve whose fibers are all isomorphic to $Y$.

Comment: @Jason Starr, so you provide a counter-example for the simply-connected case, do you know whether the condition $H^i(Y,\mathcal O)=0$ for $i>0$ is suffice to deduce $X$ being projective?

Comment: @ Michael Albanese, I have added something new to this question and I think here is a better place to discuss this question because the necessary and sufficient condition may be a research-level question.

Comment: I htink the most important counterexample is the twistor fibration of a hyperkahler manifold.

Comment: @Denis T.  Most fibers of a twistor family are not projective.

Comment: @Tom.  The blowing up of a projective plane along the base locus of a general pencil of plane cubics is $\mathcal{O}$-acyclic.

Comment: @Jason Starr, sorry, I don't know what you mean, do you mean $H^i(Y,\mathcal O)=0$  for $i>0$ is not enough to deduce the total space $X$ projective?

Comment: @Tom "... do you mean $H^i(Y,\mathcal{O})=0$ for $i>0$ isnot enough to deduce the total space $X$ projective?"  Yes, that is precisely what I mean.

Comment: @Jason Starr, thanks, but in Cao Junyan's paper, he has deduece that $X$ is a projective manifold, maybe he has added some other conditions, for example, he uses the isometric splitting property of the universal covering, which make the metric of $Y$ strictly positive, do you know if there are any other conditions added to make $X$ projective?

Comment: @Tom  I am replying to the question you asked in your post.  I am not familiar with the paper you mention by Cao Junyan.  I cannot comment on that paper.  Perhaps Cao Junyan adds a Kaehler condition (which you did not assume in your post).

Comment: @Jason Starr, do you mean if we add the condition that the total space $X$ is a Kähler manifold, then $X$ should be a projective manifold? Actually, we have this condition for X is a finite cover of a Kähler manifold (but I omitted it carelessly).

Comment: Yes, if the total space is Kaehler and if the fibers are $\mathcal{O}$-acyclic, then the total space is projective.

Comment: @Jason Starr, actually we don't need $\mathcal O$-acyclic condition, instead, we only need the condition $H^2(Y,\mathcal O)=0$ for the fiber $Y$ and the total space $X$ admits a Kähler metric, then $X$ is a projective manifold, isn't it?

Comment: "actually we don't need . . ."  Yes that is correct.

Comment: @Jason Starr, I'm afraid we have made mistakes, someone told me that the condition for the fiber $Y$ satisfying $H^2(Y,\mathcal O)$ is not enough, he claimed that there are non-algebraic complex tori $T$ of dimension 2 which contain an elliptic curve $E$. Consider the fibration $T→T/E$.

Comment: You are right; I was wrong.  If you assume that both $H^1(Y,\mathcal{O})$ and $H^2(Y,\mathcal{O})$ vanish, that should be enough.  That implies that the relative Picard scheme of the fibration is 'etale.  However, the example by @abx shows that it is not enough to assume that $H^2(Y,\mathcal{O})$ vanishes, since that only implies that the relative Picard scheme is smooth, not 'etale.

Comment: @Jason Starr the condition for fibers $H^i(Y,\mathcal O)=0$ for $i>0$ is suffice to deduce the total space $X$ being Moishezon?

Comment: Can you point out very precisely which sentence in Cao Junyan's paper you don't follow? I looked on p.405 but I don't see anything resembling your question

Comment: @YangMills, the sectence I don't follow is in p.404 "Thanks to Remark 7, we can suppose that $\omega_{Y_2}\in H^{1,1}(Y_2,\mathbb Q)$", by Remark 7, we have $H^2=H^{1,1}$ for $Y_2$, so we only need to pick a rational class in $H^2(Y_2,\mathbb R)$ which I think is not always possible since the Kähler cone of $Y_2$ may not always forms a open set in $H^{1,1}(Y_2,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: In that sentence, he starts with $(X,\omega_X)$ which is Kähler, and its universal cover which splits as $\mathbb{C}^q\times Y_1\times Y_2$. Pulling back $\omega_X$, its universal cover is also Kähler, and since submanifolds of Kähler are Kähler, it follows that $Y_2$ is Kähler too (and compact). Now the Kähler cone of a compact Kähler manifold is always open in $H^{1,1}_{\mathbb{R}}$. And for $Y_2$ we have $H^{1,1}(Y_2,\mathbb{R})=H^2(Y_2,\mathbb{R})$ by Remark 7, so...

Comment: ...he is right to claim that you can choose $\omega_X$ so that the Kähler form $\omega_{Y_2}$ that you get on $Y_2$ by the above procedure has rational cohomology class.

Comment: @YangMills，$Y_2$ is a submanifold of $\hat{X}=\tilde X/G$, and the Kähler cone of $Y_2$ is a restriction of the Kähler cone of $\hat {X}$ to $Y_2$, which may not be an open set of $H^{1,1}(Y_2,\mathbb R)$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3899428/is-a-k%c3%a4hler-class-of-the-submanifold-always-deducible-from-the-outer-space

Comment: No, what you wrote is wrong. In that sentence that you quoted, $Y_2$ is a factor in the splitting $\tilde{X}=\mathbb{C}^q\times Y_1\times Y_2$, as in item (i) of Theorem 3.3 on the same page. Also, it is completely false that the Kähler cone of a submanifold is the restriction of the Kähler cone of the ambient space, otherwise all projective manifolds would have 1-dimensional Kähler cone!  And lastly, again, the Kähler cone of every compact Kähler manifold (call it $Y_2$) is always opein in $H^{1,1}(Y_2,\mathbb{R})$

Comment: @YangMills, sorry, my expreesion has lead some confusion, I know the full Kähler cone of $Y_2$ is open in $H^{1,1}(Y_2,\mathbb R)$, but the problem is $\omega_{Y_2}$ is induced form $\omega_X$, so the induced $\omega_{Y_2}$  may not forms a full Kähler cone of $Y_2$, thus not an open set in $H^{1,1}(Y_2,\mathbb R)$, so may not contain a rational class, isn't it?