# Kähler fiber space with base and fiber projective

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $X$ be a Kähler manifold, $Y$ be a projective manifold, if $X$ exits a smooth fibration over $Y$ such that all the fibers are projective manifolds, then is $X$ a projective mannifold?

If we do not add the Kähler condtion to the total space $X$, then we have the counter-example: Hopf surface, which is a non-Kähler compact complex surface over $\mathbb CP^1$ with all the fibers are elliptic curves. So the Kähler condition is necessary, anyone have such examples?

Comment: No. There are non-algebraic complex tori $T$ of dimension $2$ which contain an elliptic curve $E$. Consider the fibration $T\rightarrow T/E$.

Comment: @abx, can you say a bit more about how to construct explict examples of such tori? For example, let $T=\mathbb C^2/\Lambda$, then what is the lattice $\Lambda$? and what is $E$? Is $T/E$ also an elliptic curve?

Comment: $T/E$ is an abelian variety of dimension 1, hence an elliptic curve. You can take $\Lambda=\mathbb{Z}e_1+\mathbb{Z}e_2+\mathbb{Z}ie_1+\mathbb{Z}i(\sqrt{2}e_1+\sqrt{3}e_2) $, with $E=$ image of $\mathbb{C}e_1$; see the Appendix of Elencwajg-Forster, Ann. Inst. Fourier 32 (1982), 25-51.

Comment: @abx, thanks for your comments, you have provided an counter-example for fibers only projective, but if we strengthen the condition of fibers $P$ to projective and $H^i(P,\mathcal O)=0,i>0$, then is the total space $X$ projective? Actually this question has already been asked here(https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373297/when-a-fibration-over-a-projective-manifold-is-projective), but I only familiar with the language of complex geometry, not  the language of algebraic geometry, so I'm not sure whether it is true.

Comment: I don't know. The conditions you put are so strong that it is hard to think of any possible counter-example.