# The projectivity of a Kähler fiber space over a projective manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold, $B$ being a complex projective manifold, for a smooth fibration:$\pi:X\rightarrow B$ such that all the fibers are a projective manifold $Y$ with $H^i(Y,\mathcal O)=0,i>0$, then is $X$ a projective manifold?

This question is a trial to understand Prof Jason Starr's comments on [this question] ([When a fibration over a projective manifold is projective?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373297/when-a-fibration-over-a-projective-manifold-is-projective)), according to him, if we remove the Kähler condition for $X$, only require $X$ being a complex manifold, then $X$ may not always be a projective manifold, he commented:

> The blowing up of a projective plane along the base locus of a general pencil of plane cubics is $\mathcal O$-acyclic.

I wonder in this case, is $X$ a Moishezon manifold? Since he later said that if we add the Kähler condition for the total space $X$, then it is enough to deduce $X$ being projective. And I know that Moishezon+Kähler=projective. So my first question is:

1. without the Kähler condition, only require the fibers $\mathcal O$-acyclic and base space projective, can we deduce the total space is a Moishezon manifold?

And if my understanding is right, Jason's method can be summarised like that: $H^1(Y,\mathcal O)$ and $H^2(Y,\mathcal O)$ vanish implies that the relative Picard scheme of the fibration is étale.

But I can't see why a relative Picard scheme being étale is enough to deduce the total space $X$ being a projective manifold. As a begginer of complex geometry, I am only familiar with the language of
Griffiths&Harris or Huybrechts. So could someone help me expain Prof Jason Starr's method in the language of complex geometry or recommand me some reference or provide a new method? Any comments is welcome.